# Sending server-side system messages to a channel?

Tags: getstream-io

How can we create and send system messages to a channel from the server (Node/JS)? And how do we differentiate those from regular messages and style them? We're using the iOS SDK and the UI Kit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System messages are something that Stream is planning on implementing soon, it's in the backlog.

For now, as a workaround,

1. Create a `system-user` which is instantiated server-side
2. Channels that you'd like to send system messages to would be instantiated server-side and creates by `system-user`
3. Create a custom message type
4. Any message sent from `message.user_id = system-user` can be rendered using this custom message type

Comment: Any updates on this, where can I find this backlog item?